# My Windows mobile 6.5 application very slow?

Tags: windows, mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

I have developed a Windows phone 6.5 application.  This app is running perfectly, but some times it works horrible slow.

I have tried ClearTemp application( it clear the garbage / unused memory) but no changes in my application ?

I need to give a demo to my clients.  If it is happens in front of them it would be worst .

So please give me any idea to run the application perfectly.  What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem of slowness can have different sources. MS provides the free PowerToys for compact framework to analyse .NETCF applications: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13442

There are various articles on how to use the performance monitor: search for "msdn compact framework performance".

Possibly you are running threads with no sleep cycles.

Or another thread on the device uses much CPU cycles.

You can optimize loading of forms by caching them.

Without having more information about the app it is hard to suggest tipps for the performance.

Possibly my CPUMonitor helps you:  http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/12/14/mobile-development-a-remote-cpu-monitor-and-cpu-usage-analysis/ (needs a network).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, 
i used 2 timer in my application i forget to disable one timer when  another timer  runs its own method .

so i corrected now .it is working very fine.

for example

1.timer1_method ()
2.{
3.timer2.enable=false ;
4.//write ur method here

7.////////////////////
8.timer2.enable=true ;
9.}

and also vice versa for timer2 method